Can Noun Phrases qualify Latin adjectives
In LLPSI FR in Chapter 19 at line 90 is the following excerpt.

“[...] Decem annī longum est tempus, sed amor meus tempore nōn minuitur. [...]”

My inference for translation is:
Ten years is a long time, but in (that) time my love does not diminish.
My concern arises with longum because it is a adjective that does not agree with annī (so I may risk negative transference from my experience with English), and I am not familiar with the idea of qualifying an adjective with a Noun Phrase in Latin.
Question:
Is longum qualified with decem annī, or perhaps would a reasonable translation differ?

I am a bit confused as to what your problem is. The translation provided is quite literal: longum tempus is exactly parallel to 'a long time'. The adjective agrees with tempus, a neuter noun. anni of course is plural, not genitive singular, if that is the source of confusion.

Longum is an adjective (neuter nominative singular), it modifies a noun, that noun is sitting right next to it, it agrees with it, you have already determined the meaning "a long time," the grammar is dead simple. The sentence means what you think means.
(I imagine in English someone might say: "the time was a long ten years." That would be difficult to render literally in Latin without resorting to "ten long years." But that is not the case here.)
